# Problem with Netbeans IDE when putting swing components in a jFrame

Tags: swing, netbeans

I`m making a GUI for my java program using Swing Components and Netbeans IDE.

My problem is that I can't easily put the components on where ever I like in the jFrame. When I drag and drop a component on the frame, other components of the frame start changing their positions and even sizes! Have anybody else face such problem? Should I edit or configure anything?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` is the granddaddy of layouts. You can do virtually anything you want to do with it, but it has a bit of a learning curve. But what you will probably find is that you chose different `LayoutManagers` for different purposes.

NetBeans is great for `GridBagLayout` because you can tweak the `GridBagConstraints` properties int the WYSIWYG editor untill you like what you see.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. My problem was that I wasn't using an appropriate Layout.
I should set the layout of the jFrame I`m using by right clicking on it in the inspector window to Null.